# duplicate/clone and altering content in 11ty

Tags: javascript, eleventy

I have a standard group of Eleventy posts (markdown files in a folder) which build to the standard site.com/slug/index.html path. I would also like to generate an additional meta file for each of these posts at build time, which is of a different format, and would live at something like site.com/slug/file.ics. So the permalink must change. I only want to have to manage one set of files, the original markdown files contain the meta information required to build the additional file in the front-matter. So I assumed I'd be able to somehow use 2 different templates to manage how the final files were generated.

I've tried a handful of things, none work.

Creating a collection via glob, then using Eleventy's pagination did not work (at least not the way I did it):

```js
  /* in the config file */
  config.addCollection('articles_meta', (collectionAPI) => {
    return collectionAPI.getFilteredByGlob('_content/articles/*.md')
  })
```

```js
/* in an article_meta.md */
---js
    pagination: {
      data: 'collections.articles_meta',
      size: 1,
      alias: 'article_meta'
    },
  
    permalink: function (data) {
        return (
          "/articles/" +
          `${this.slug(data.title)}` +
          "/file.ics"
        );
      },
  }
---
```

Which gives me an error about not finding `collections.articles_meta`. Similarly if I just try to create a data file that returns the collection directly I get the same error. I suspect I'm using the wrong tools for the job. Any suggestions?